# Easiest way to determine the size of an image when within an ImageView

Tags: ios, ios6, uiimageview, uiimage

I have a large image which is different in size all the time. The image is placed into a `UIImageView`. At present, for this example the image is kept in its original size but in future would be optimised to fit for performance.

Lets say an example 1 is : 1600x1200
An example 2 is: 900x2400

If a `UIImageView` takes up the whole view screen, what is the easiest way to determine the size of the image within the `UIImageView`.

Is there someway to determine this without doing the maths? If the image view has an Aspect to Fit style for content mode. Also if the view controller is shown in Landscape/Portrait the image would change in size shown. I am trying to determine the frame of the actual image within the UIImageView.

Of course with maths I could do something like this:

```
ratio = imageview.height / pushedPhoto.height
frameWidth = ratio * pushedPhoto.width
frameHeight = ratio * pushedPhoto.height
frameX = (imageview.height-frameHeight)/2;
frameY = (imageview.width-frameWidth)/2;
```

But I am wondering if there is an easier route to find this out.

Comment: @GabrielePetronella That only works if the image and the imageView have the same aspect ratio.

Comment: maths get you want you want

Comment: `imageView.image.size` gives you the `CGSize` of the original image

Comment: @GabrielePetronella - Is the bounds not the whole UIImageView size? While I am looking for the frame of the image once scaled down into the uiimageview.

Comment: @progrmr - This would give me the original size of the image not the scaled down image size. I need the frame for the image once scaled down into the uiimageview

Comment: The size of the `UIImageView` is in its frame property if it is on screen, just access `imageView.frame.size` for its actual on screen size.

Comment: Now I think I see what you're asking, your image doesn't fill the UIImageView exactly.  Its size within the UIImageView will depend on how you set the `contentMode` and `contentStretch` properties on the UIImageView.  How are those set?

Comment: @progrmr - Yes correct. It is Aspect Fit, so it keeps the aspect ratio of the image and makes it fit within the UIImageView. I am then trying to find the size of the image within the image view. So that I can later find a point specifically in that image -regardless of the original image size/rotation. Im thinking I can only do this with some maths, but interested to know if there is a simpler accessible property to find this.

Comment: With Aspect Fit you'll have to calculate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have to complete with maths for this. Please feel free to answer in the future, should there be an alternate.

Answer (score 0):

The `UIImage` class actually has a property called `size`, which holds the dimensions of the image. Wouldn't this be enough for you?

> **size**
>
> The dimensions of the image, taking orientation into account. (read-only)
>
> @property(nonatomic, readonly) CGSize size

You could check for `imageView.image.size`

Comment: I do not think the image size is what I am looking for. That would be the examples in my question like 1600x1200. But when the image is shown in the image view it is scaled down to fit into the view. I am looking for the new frame of the image within the uiimageview